# ruby match and scan not matching a pattern the same way?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to parse out some inforamtion from multiple records.  One of the items I'm interested in can have multiple entries in a string.  My thought was just to return an array of all the matching values, but I'm having trouble with the results. For example:

```
> s = '>ctg7180000000043_1204 selected_feature: CDS loc=299156..299605;/db_xref="GO:0007155";/db_xref="GO:0009289";'
 => ">ctg7180000000043_1204 selected_feature: CDS loc=299156..299605;/db_xref=\"GO:0007155\";/db_xref=\"GO:0009289\";"
> s.match('db_xref="[^"]+')
 => #<MatchData "db_xref=\"GO:0007155">
> s.scan('db_xref="[^"]+')
 => []
```

Anyway, why does match, er, match and scan does not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String#match` converts its argument to a Regexp, `String#scan` searches for a literal string if that's what you give it, giving #scan a Regexp gives it the same matches. Reference the ri docs for String#match and String#scan. Try the following in irb:

```
regex = /db_xref="[^"]+/
s.match(regex)
=> #<MatchData "db_xref=\"GO:0007155">
s.scan(regex)
=> ["db_xref=\"GO:0007155", "db_xref=\"GO:0009289"]
```

scan will also continue to match over the entire string, while match stops at the first pattern (you can then give it a start offset to continue if you need).

Comment: Ah, match converts a string to a regex and scan does not.  So you have to use // as the delimeters in scan if you want it to interpret the regex AS a regex.  Got it, thanks!